# When exactly is .save called in Backbone.js when you call Collection.create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I've this working code here.

I had an error in the underscore template prior and what I noticed was, model wasn't being saved to database since rendering wasn't working due to bad template. This should imply that model.save() is called after rendering. Or maybe, collections.create() does all the saving job and model.save() is not called at all?

How exactly is the model data being saved in the database by the following code?

```
$(function(){
Todos = new TodoList.Collections.Todos;
TodoList.Views.TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "li",
    events: {},
    initialize: function(){},
    template: _.template('<li> <%= task %></li>'),
    render: function(){
        var todo = this.model.toJSON();
        //alert("render: " + JSON.stringify(todo));
        return this.template(todo);
    }
});

TodoView = TodoList.Views.TodoView;

TodoList.Views.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#todo_app"),
    events: {
        "submit form#new_todo": "createTodo",
        "click div.new-todo-btn" : "showFormNew"
    },
    showFormNew: function(){
        $(".new-todo-form").toggle();
    },
    initialize: function(){
        _.bindAll(this, 'addOne', 'addAll','render');
        Todos.bind("add", this.addOne);
        Todos.bind("reset", this.addAll);
        Todos.bind("all", this.render);
        Todos.fetch();
    },

    addOne: function(todo){
        var view = new TodoView({model: todo});
        this.$("#todo_list").append(view.render());
    },

    addAll: function(){
        Todos.each(this.addOne);
    },

    newAttributes: function(event){
        var new_todo_form = $(event.currentTarget).serializeObject();
        return {
                'task': new_todo_form["todo[task]"],
                'done': new_todo_form["todo[done]"]
        };
    },

    createTodo: function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var params = this.newAttributes(e);
        Todos.create(params);
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know what is happening in any particular backbone.js method then the annotated source is really useful. The Backbone source is quite small and fairly easy to follow.

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-99

You can see that `Collection.create` does call the `model.save` method unless model validation fails.

The sequence of events here is (if there are no errors):

- User fills in the `new_todo` form and submits it.
- The `createTodo` method is called which calls TodoList.create.
- `Collection.create` calls `model.save`.
- The success callback passed to `model.save` will add the new model to the collection.
- The `add` event fires on the collection causing the `TodoList.addOne` method to be called which creates the new `TodoView`.

Comment: This helped. Thanks. I'll go through the source now.

Answer (score 1):

It's not at all certain that the code above is successfully saving the model data. You're not attaching to the "sync" event on the model, which is called when the model has been successfully created on the server. You're also not attaching to the "error" event which will be fired if there is any issue saving the model.

Collection.create calls Model.save directly btw.

Comment: The code is working without attaching sync event. The new items are being loaded in the collection and added to the database.